# text in latex latin

Tags: lipsum

I am getting this text in the PDF after compiling in text studio.
I did not write it in the source and cannot find its words in the original text.
Any ideas?
I have the following packages in the document.

This is the text :

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing
>   vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
>   magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
>   fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
>   fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
>   quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla,
>   malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus.
>   Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
>   rutrum.
>   Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
>   lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum,
>   erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse
>   ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
>   montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque
>   cursus luctus mauris.
>   Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero.
>   Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin
>   fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia.
>   Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc
>   eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non
>   enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus.
>   Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.
>   Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem
>   ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis
>   augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida
>   32
>   sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus
>   nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.
>   Fusce mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus. Sed bibendum, nulla a faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies
>   tellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl. Vestibulum diam. Aliquam pellentesque, augue quis sagittis posuere,
>   turpis lacus congue quam, in hendrerit risus eros eget felis. Maecenas eget erat in sapien mattis porttitor.
>   Vestibulum porttitor. Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis eu lacus commodo facilisis. Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim
>   interdum, justo lectus sagittis dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus dui. Mauris tempor ligula sed lacus. Duis
>   cursus enim ut augue. Cras ac magna. Cras nulla. Nulla egestas. Curabitur a leo. Quisque egestas wisi eget
>   nunc. Nam feugiat lacus vel est. Curabitur consectetuer.
>   Figure 5: Gini eect on Secondary school enrollment
>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit
>   amet, consectetuer adipiscing
>   elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam
>   arcu libero, nonummy eget,
>   consectetuer id, vulputate a,
>   magna. Donec vehicula augue
>   eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
>   et netus et malesuada fames
>   ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut
>   leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
>   placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices
>   bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur
>   auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis,
>   diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
>   Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
>   lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum,
>   erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse
>   ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
>   montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque
>   33
>   cursus luctus mauris.

Comment: Do you have a `\lipsum` anywhere?

Comment: One can say nothing about this without seeing LaTeX code that produces the issue. The most probable cause is the presence of `\usepackage{lipsum}` in the preamble and of `\lipsum` in the body of the document.

Comment: @Werner, @egreg: you guys get back to TeX.sx! `:)`

Comment: A `\lipsum` somewhere seems to be the most reasonable point here. Provide code if you are ABSOLUTELY sure there isn't.

Comment: @PauloCereda: Automagically, we're back!

Comment: @Werner: Witchcraft! `:)`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 9):

This is often-used "dummy text" suggesting that there is a placeholder in the template for which you did not overwrite the text with your own. It's used to show "bla bla bla here is some text and this is what it will look like" but trying to look more interesting. It is scrambled Latin that has been in use since the 1500's, although the original text is over 2000 years old. See http://www.lipsum.com

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.