# Why some two column text disappear when adding wide figure?

Tags: two-column, tikz-trees

I am writing a scientific two-column paper, and I would like to add a wide feagure that is located over the two columns. Luckily, I was able to make it after reading some articles here, but it seems quite harder to force it to a specific place by using `[H]` or `[ht!]`. It went to very bottom, and I cannot go to the top of the following page as I want it to be. When I deleted some unwanted text, it went up but with deleting some thing that I have not touched. Look at the code that I wrote.

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\onecolumn
\begin{tabular}{|llll|}

\hline

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {is} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {precise }};
    \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
    node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
 & 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {and}[sibling distance=1.5cm]
            child {node {exact}}
            child {node {accurate}}
        };
    \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
    node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}

& $\Longrightarrow$ %could not apply baseline
&

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {if} [sibling distance=4cm]
        child {node {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
            child {node {X}}
            child {node {precise }
        }}
        child {node {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
            child {node {X} }
            child {node {and}[sibling distance=1.5cm]
                child {node {exact}}
                child {node {accurate}}
    }};
;

     \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
     node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{An example of the reconstructing sentences in out system}
\label{normalization}


\end{figure}
\twocolumn
```

Forget about the arrow that I could not aligning it vertically with the trees. I tried to make the variable X is the baseline as it is written in all trees but I could not. The main problem is that where the deleted text go to when I clean some above texts? If the problem with

[image]

```
\onecolumn
```

and

```
\twocolumn
```

Then How should I do it?

Comment: `figure*` (mind the asterisk)

Comment: It should be noted that figure* does not support h (or H).  The easy solution is to use multicols instead of twocolumn and place the image (using \captionof{figure}{,,,}) in one column mode.  A more difficult approach is to place a gap precisely at the right spot in the other (using \rule{0pt}{...}).

Comment: `\onecolumn` inside `figure` is certainly wrong. What you need is definitely `figure*`.

Comment: I changes '\onecolumn' inside and outside figure*, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `strip` environment from `cuted` in the place of a `figure*` environment. Here is a code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cuted, caption, makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} \usepackage[showframe, twocolumn, columnsep=1.5em]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{strip}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|ll@{\raisebox{14.6ex}{$ =⇒ $}\enspace}l|}

\hline

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {is} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {precise }};
    \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
    node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
 &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {and}[sibling distance=1.5cm]
            child {node {exact}}
            child {node {accurate}}
        };
    \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
    node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}

 &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {if} [sibling distance=4cm]
        child {node {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
            child {node {X}}
            child {node {precise }
        }}
        child {node {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
            child {node {X} }
            child {node {and}[sibling distance=1.5cm]
                child {node {exact}}
                child {node {accurate}}
    }};
;

     \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
     node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\captionof{figure}{An example of the reconstructing sentences in out system}
\label{normalization}


\end{strip}
\lipsum[2-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You also can use the `figure*` environment. In this case, you have a float which will be placed at the top of a page, usually the next one:

```
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|ll@{\raisebox{14.6ex}{$ =⇒ $}\enspace}l|}

\hline

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {is} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {precise }};
    \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
    node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
 &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
        child {node {X}}
        child {node {and}[sibling distance=1.5cm]
            child {node {exact}}
            child {node {accurate}}
        };
    \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
    node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture}

 &
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (is-root) {if} [sibling distance=4cm]
        child {node {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
            child {node {X}}
            child {node {precise }
        }}
        child {node {is} [sibling distance=2cm]
            child {node {X} }
            child {node {and}[sibling distance=1.5cm]
                child {node {exact}}
                child {node {accurate}}
    }};
;

     \path (is-root) +(0,-2.5\tikzleveldistance)
     node {\textit{}};
\end{tikzpicture} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{An example of the reconstructing sentences in out system}
\label{normalization}


\end{figure*}
\lipsum[2-12]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it with and without \onecolumn and \twocolumn .. it gave me a different error .. Float(s) Lost !

Comment: Don't use \onecolumn nor \twocolumn. A `strip` environment is *not* a float (whence `\caption of{figure}` in the place of `\caption`.  Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: It is weird, LaTeX Erro: Float(s) lost. (\end{document})

Comment: I've completed your code to show how it works (and slightly modified to place the arrow higher). Is it something like that you want?

Comment: Good move, even though I was looking for it to be aligned to the following top page as it should not be in the middle. I created it in the second page and I would like it to be at the top of the third. However, half of the text that following this figure has disappeared.

Comment: I didn't understand that, as you mentioned the `H` specifier. What you want taachieve is normally obtained by the  `figure*` environment.

Comment: @lol745: I've completed my answer with an example code for the`figure*` environment.

Comment: That is much better. Thank you very much. However, there is a text before and after the shape I did not write it.. For example.

I have: 

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa(Figure)bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

the new shape is 

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa3590850913850913(Figure)35909-0359-3019-3590bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see  what you mean. What happens to the text?

Comment: There something else, happened, which is mentioned here [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134774/text-in-latex-latin] 
The latin text, it occurs because of our use of **lipsum**, any way to get rid of it? (it is exactly the same as the text in this link).

Comment: Are you using the `lipsum` package, and the `\lipsum` command?  I use it in my answer to have some dummy text, but if you have text of your own, remove the `\lipsum` commands.

Comment: You are right, now it is better, but is there any way to force strip{} to be at the top of a page like figure?

Comment: You can, with the `atbegshi` package, and the command:`\AtBeginShipoutNext{\leavevmode\begin{strip} ... \end{strip}}`,  but  I don't see what  it brings as compared to the  `figure*` environment?